# R Caret, how to have the same features in training and applying dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, classification, r-caret

I'm working with the `caret` package, training a model for text classification, but I've faced a problem that bugs me and I'm not finding a proper solution.

I got a `data.frame` of training like this:

```
training <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1),y = c(0,1,0), z = c(1,1,1), result =c('good','good','bad'))
training
  x y z result
1 0 0 1   good
2 0 1 1   good
3 1 0 1    bad
```

So I train my model like this:

```
library(caret)
svm_mod <- train(sent ~ .,df,  method = "svmLinear")
# There were 42 warnings (use warnings() to see them)  Some warnings, not the point of the question
```

Now let's skip the testing part, let's think that's ok.

Now I've the real work, i.e. predict unknown data. My problem is that the "applying" data can have different columns from the `training` dataset, and predicting is not always permitted:

```
# if the columns are the same, it's ok
applying <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1),y = c(0,1,0), z = c(0,1,1))
predict(svm_mod, applying)

# if the columns in applying are more than in train, it's ok
applying <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1),y = c(0,1,0), z = c(0,1,1), k=c(1,1,1))
predict(svm_mod, applying)

# if in applying is missing a column that is in train it does not work:
applying <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1),y = c(0,1,0))
predict(svm_mod, applying)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'z' not found
```

Now the solution should be to add all the missing column in training as 0s:

```
applying$z <- 0
```

in the `applying` dataset, but I find it not so correct/nice. Are there a correct solution to do this? I've read several question about this (my favourite is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539633/error-in-evalpredvars-data-env-object-rm-not-found), my question is about finding a workaround about this issue).

My data are phrases, and I'm using document term matrix as inputs, in a production environment, this mean that's going to have newer input, without the columns in train.

Comment: which package have you used to create the dtm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recreate same DocumentTermMatrix with new (test) data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630627/how-to-recreate-same-documenttermmatrix-with-new-test-data)

Comment: @missuse I'm using tm package. I'm going to look at the suggested question, thanks a lot.

Comment: I am glad if I can help. I suggest using  text2vec as per its creators suggestion (Dmitriy Selivanov - 2nd answer in the linked question).